# Making a anchor tag in a different page when click on button on one page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I had this code of making anchor tag

```
<script>
function showlogout() {       
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("demo");
    var aTag = document.createElement('a');
    aTag.setAttribute('href',"www.google.com");
    aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
    mydiv.appendChild(aTag);   
}
</script>
```

I had a form code on same page

```
 <form action="/login" method="post" onclick="showlogout()" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

But when I m directed to the login page after logging the details 
     I m not able to see this  anchor tag while able to see all other details
    which/login page is rendering.

I want anchor tag should be visible on /login page 
as soon as I login the details on hitting login button.

Comment: Put javascript code on `login` page.

Comment: Actually from /login page on successful login I m routed to "/" automatically  page which has some blogs already on it,I want this anchor tag  to appear at this "/" page.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to append to a div that doesn't exist. The problem line is `var mydiv = document.getElementById("demo");`
You need to add a div with the id of `demo` and it will work. You may also need to prevent the default form submit action.
To do that:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

EDIT: 
Well, that's how you would get it to work on the same page anyways... if you want to pass a link from one page to another, you have to use some method of persisting the changes, like using cookies or local storage.

Comment: Actually from /login page on successful login I m routed to "/" automatically  page which has some blogs already on it,I want this anchor tag  to appear at this "/" page.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Are you trying to build your own authentication system? Why do you need to generate the link on the login page? You probably need to use some kind of storage, like cookies or something.

Comment: Yes I m using passport.js,I will look into the cookies, thanks